# easyui 1.4.5 tree node hyperlink

Tags: jquery-easyui

I am using easyui 1.4.5. I want to know how to add hyperlink to each node.

[tree example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4cAl.png)

I added attributes like this

```
"attributes":{
        "url":"www.google.com" 
    }
```

but it doesn't work. Anyone can help me? Appreciate in advanced.